# Socket.IO server + Socket.IO-client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Im actually desperate now. I need to design and code solution I've never even thought I'd be making, and it seems completely unrealistic to achieve (for me) with clean express. But I might be wrong.

What I need is:

- REST API - done
- Socket.IO server - done
- bunch of Socket.IO-client connections - can be done

But now, what I need is to some efficient way of making it, to communicate with each other. So the app has to be basically a bridge between all of them. I was thinking of using some kind of state managing library, like Redux solution, that way I (at least I think) could achieve it pretty easy. But I also haven't found any of this kind, for the node, or neither found how to achieve it on the backend.

So the question is: what's the best solution, to achieve one-to-many and many-to-one communication between multiple socket.io connections? Again, to make it clear.

**socket-client connection** = connecting to already existing server, as a node app.

I am not speaking of making simple solution for clients to communicate between each other on 1 server. I want to create 1 server, and to connect to multiple others.

Comment: Am I getting this right? You want to get multiple websocket connections to different servers from the same browser/client window?

Comment: @MildlySerious no. I was worried I did not explain it well enough. I want all connections to be made from the Node app. The server. To other servers. Only problem i have is the architecture, data passed to server I create, has to be passed to those client-connections. Is it clear that way?

Comment: That is more clear. Is there a reason to use socket.io for this? Seems like a problem where a message queue or pubsub service would be the correct solution.

Comment: There actually is. I want to create 3 independent apps. A client (electron based). A server. And bot instances - each bot has it's own server. The idea I had, was to achieve some kind of bridge between, so I can parse the data. But I agree, pubsub would be better solution for this. Although, do you have any idea how to achieve what I want? I feel like I need to expand my knowledge on this area.

Comment: I'll make an attempt at an answer

Comment: Awesome, I'll be waiting!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, what you probably want to do is to create one "server" application, then connect your Electron app as well as the bots as clients to that server.

For the bots, which would be running as their own node scripts, you would be using the [`socket.io-client`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) package, and then use that the same way you use the client in the browser. Call `io()` with your connection settings, get a socket from that, and start binding your events as usual:

```
let io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = io('http://YOUR_SERVER_IP/');

socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

If you want to tell the difference between the bots and the Electron clients, I would send out some special event on connect, that your server can then handle:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('identify_as_bot', {id: IDENTIFIER})
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That's actually what I tried to avoid. Going that way, bot instances are dependable on one, exact server. I want bots to be available for multi-server connection

Comment: You can still open multiple sockets using multiple calls to `io`, or connect to a central server, receive an IP for the actual target server, then connect to that. You can get quite creative with things like that. Or provide a pool of server IPs and randomly connect to one. Anything goes.

Comment: but that requires me to create and update those whitelists. And as what you describe is indeed proper usage of sockets, this project isn't for commercial usage, it's just for learning purposes, I wanted to challange myself with something I never tried before. :P

Comment: That's a good mindset to have! If there's any place where "building stuff to learn" is true, it's webdev. I'm not sure where you're trying to go, though. Other options to find IPs would be relying on DNS, either through DynDNS services or DNS load balancing. Or if you want to go all out, use some mesh/decentralized network algorithms for discovery. That problem is not limited to socket.io :P

Comment: Thank you alot! I'll play with few ideas I have, maybe finally will do it way you proposed